# Fetching data using where clause

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my categories. If i click on a category then it goes to its view page, and show all products related with this selected category.
[image]

I am trying like this.But it is not working.Can you please anyone help me to solve this problem?I am using 3  tables for this situation.
1.categories[image: enter image description herecategories table]

2.products
[image]
3.product_cat

[image]

Controller:

```
<?php 
class Clothing extends Controller{

    function product_details(){
        $id=$this->uri->segment(3);

        $this->load->model('Products_model');
        $data['products']=$this->Products_model->product_details($id);

        //$this->load->view('clothe',$data);
    }
}

?>
```

Model:

```
<?php
class Products_model extends Model {
    function product_details($id){
                    $query=$this->db->select("*")
                    ->from("product_cat")
                    ->where("categories_id",$id);
                    return $query;
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <?php  foreach ($products as $v_menu) { ?>
                    <?php echo $v_menu; ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In model  modify your query as                                                                  $query=$this->db->select("*")
                    ->from("product_cat")
                    ->where("categories_id",$id)->get()->result();

Comment: Oh brother. thanks lot. may god bless you. Thanks again.

Comment: Version of CodeIgniter you are using is old at least [more than 6 years](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html#version-1-7-2) now and it is not considered as secure one. Port your code to v 3.0.x

Comment: can you please, i got the product id's related with category id? and now how can i fetch the product details using this product id from the table products given above in the image?

Comment: I tried like this: 
$results=  $this->db->select("*") ->from("products") ->where("id",$key)->get()->result();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two tables products and product_cat as below so that you can get the product details too-

```
return $query=$this->db->select('*')
        ->from('product a')
        ->from('product_cat p')
        ->where("p.product_id = a.id")
        ->where('p.categories_id =', $id)
        ->get()->result();
```

Comment: oh Thanks lot :) sa-7

Comment: i have no reputation for accept the answer :( . sorry. But it works :)

Comment: ohhk :(  http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Good to hear that it works. :)

Comment: When your reputation grows please do mark the answer as correct,for all your questions if getting a working answer do tick and vote for it only then other viewer's also can try to implement on it. thanks :)